# How to find directory of a uploading file in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc

.Net MVC. I want to load a XML file from my directory and the directory path can be random. I can load the XML file but I need also to know my file directory path. Can anybody give me the idea how can I get the full directory path of my XML file. Suppose the file is in `C:\abc\test.xml` or `D:\cde\test2.xml`. If I load 1st one I need the directory path as `C:\abc\test.xml` in my application.

Comment: If you loaded the file, don't you already have the full path??

Comment: You want to know the full directory of the file on the client's machine? That's not really possible within the browser's sandbox. You would need additional program to run on the client's machine.

Comment: You can use Server.MapPath("~/abc//test.xml") to get directory path

Comment: @ShakirAhamed Thanks for your comment. But this one is howing "c:\\users\\hasan\\documents\\visual studio 2015\\Projects\\PPGWeb\\PPGWeb\\" directory where I don't have any test.xml file.

Comment: Which version of ASP.NET / MVC?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC 5.0 @SimonOrdo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for my late answer. The problem was that I did not get full directory path to read the file. Then I created a cache memory to save the file and read it. It is just like,
var fileSavePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/XMLFiles"), fileName);